# Need Platform SDK for VC6

Tags: visual-c++-6, platform-sdk

Does anyone know where I can download the last Platform SDK to work with VC6? The links I could find by Googling all seem to be dead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to find it here... (official or not)

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/FebruaryPlatformSDK

Answer (score 4):

If you have an MSDN subscription, the Platform SDK (February 2003) and others are available under **"Tools and Resources -> Platform SDK and DDKs"**

Answer (score 3):

The last Windows Platform SDK that fully supported VC6 was the Windows 2003 SDK, February 2003. However, through legitimate channels, you can not find this SDK for download anymore, and it looks like no one even has it for ordering, as links to the order sites are dead as well.

See this old MSDN blog post about the unavailability of the PSDK online, and the link to order it is dead: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2006/06/20/640172.aspx

However, not all hope is lost. From this more recent post on the MSDN forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssdk/thread/d63fb448-c417-4f8e-9260-5a8082daa2af

As Karin Meier says, you can obtain a copy of the February 2003 PSDK from this site:

http://mssdk.orderport.net/22221848/showall.asp

The disc itself doesn't cost anything, but you will probably have to pay shipping.

And of course, unless it is absolutely necessary to use VC6, I'd recommend moving up to a current and supported version of the VC++ compiler.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, ask around the office... you might get lucky and find someone with the orignal CDs from an MSDN subscription.

Answer (score 0):

On official [Windows® Server 2003 SP1 Platform SDK Web Install](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6510) page, quote:

```
This SDK does not support working with Microsoft Visual C/C++®, 6.0 as
support for VC 6.0 has ended. The last SDK that will work with VC
6.0 is the February 2003 Edition, you can order a CD on the
fulfillment site. Side by side installations are not supported.
```

Links to download *Platform SDK February 2003 Edition* in case you have not subscribed to MSDN:

```
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.1.cab
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.2.cab
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.3.cab
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.4.cab
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.5.cab
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.6.cab
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.7.cab
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.8.cab
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.9.cab
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.10.cab
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.11.cab
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.12.cab
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.13.cab
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/PSDK-FULL.bat
http://download.microsoft.com/download/platformsdk/sdk/update/win98mexp/en-us/3790.0/FULL/Extract.exe
```

Term of use available after unpacking distribution.

If that links once disappear try http://archive.org/web/ or contact members of https://winworldpc.com/ or similar comunity for **abandonware**.

For example all `.cab` available on https://web.archive.org/web/20100318065128/http://www.microsoft.com/msdownload/platformsdk/sdkupdate/psdk-full.htm page.