# Can the PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION be used with the VC6 for the getting the Print/Print Preview completion?

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++, printing, visual-c++-6, print-preview

On searching the answers for my long unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293786/notification-for-the-end-of-printing-and-print-preview-of-the-chtmlview-and-deri), I found somewhat a relevant [question[answered]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376618/how-to-detect-print-command-has-finished-in-twebbrowser) found here.

But I am unable to get the same close notifications in VC6.

Can you help please on this?

Comment: It was likely introduced to the Windows headers after the SDK that shipped with VC6. It is time to update compilers, or at least [update your SDK to the newest possible version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018337/need-platform-sdk-for-vc6).

Comment: Thanks Cody. But Can I use the logic of PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION valuse for getting the close notification in VC6 CHtmlView::ExecWB()?